# Routes not working correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor, coffeescript, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm using a flowrouter for routing(with blaze layout), when route didn't contain a variable, then it's work fine in Internet Explorer, but when I've trying to go to routes with variables then flowrouter shows 404 page. It's occurs only in Internet Explorer.

```
#This route works fine
FlowRouter.route '/products', 
  name: 'Products.index',
  action: () -> 
    BlazeLayout.render('index', {main: 'productIndex', head: 'header'}) 

#But instead of this route flowrouter shows 404 page
FlowRouter.route '/products/:id', 
  name: 'Products.page',
  action: () ->
    BlazeLayout.render('index', {main: 'currProductPage', head: 'header'})
```

Comment: What URL produces error?

Comment: For example "/products/izoproflex"

Comment: Are you using any webserver on top of Meteor? `nginx`, `apache` etc?

Comment: I'm using nginx.

Comment: Share your `nginx` config as well, please